# Shorthand expression for an if ( $a == $b || $a == $c ) statement

Tags: php, regex, if-statement, operators, expression

I know this code will work:

```
echo ( $a == $b || $a == $c ) ? "Yes" : "No";
```

That can be read like:

> if $a is equal to $b or $a is equal to $c

Is there a way to make it more shorter like:

> if $a is equal to $b or $c

I have tried a lot including this but still no luck:

```
echo ( $a == ( $b xor $c ) ) ? "Yes" : "No";
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php):

```
var_dump(in_array($a, [$b, $c]));
```

with your example:

```
echo in_array($a, [$b, $c]) ? 'Yes' : 'No';
```

Note: this syntax is only useful if you have more than 2 values. For few values `$a == $b || $a == $c` does the job well and is probably faster.

Comment: Beat me to it, that's what I was going to suggest.

Answer (score 1):

These are two alternatives, but they will both take longer to execute than the code you posted because they rely on more complex functions.

```
preg_match('/^('.$b.'|'.$c.')$/',$a) === 0

in_array($a,array($b,$c)) === true
```

If you put the condition more likely to be true as the first expression, in most cases, PHP will evaluate the expression as true and not test the second expression.

Comment: _"...but they will both take longer to execute than the code you posted because they rely on more complex functions."_ +1