# Shorthand expression for an if ( $a == $b and $a == $c ) statement in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, operators, expression

Recently, I posted [a question about `if ( $a == $b or $a == $c )` expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30286633/4883372). Now I want to know if there's also a shorthand expression for this code:

```
if ( $a == $b && $a == $c ) { /*statement*/ }
```

That code can be read like *"if $a is equal to $b and $a is equal to $c"*.

Is there code that's more shorter that can be read like:

> if ( $a is equal to ( $b and $c ) ) { /*statement*/ }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are testing if $a is equal to $b and $c this logically results in $b being equal to $c, I don't know how much shorter this would be but if you wanted to quickly test if all prepossed values are the same you could create an array of them and call [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php). If the length of the resulting array is 1 then they are all equal to each other. I imagine this would only be easier if you had a large set of values, as the syntax might obscure your intent.

Comment: Accepted if you use to compare more values, or just use `($a==$b && $a==$c)` to compare few values for performance. To compare a common beginning, you better [check my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30295383/4883372)..

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer upon experimenting while my question is not yet posted:

```
if ( $a == ( $b & $c ) ) { /*statement*/ }
```

I just want to share it.. *(And no, I'm developing a WordPress theme and this is unintentional!)*

Comment: Your answer is indeed false, for example: `var_dump('cat' == ('cat' & 'catterpillar'));` returns `true` because the two words have a common begining.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Upon retesting, `( 'a' == ( 'ab' & 'ac' ) )` returns `false` but `( 'a' == ( 'ab' & 'a' ) )` returns `true`. Could you provide a better solution for that?

Comment: There is no better solution, Jason Sperske way is an alternative `var_dump((array)'cat' == array_unique('cat', 'cat'))` useful for more items, but for few items the test `$a==$b && $b==$c` is the most performant way.

Comment: 'cat' == ( 'cat' == 'catterpillar' );